# What does 3 to 5 api interfaces mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

For an interview, I'm asked to build a SPA website with 3-5 api interfaces.  Specifically, they want a chart that updates every 10 seconds.  Now, I'm confused what this means.  If I have a CRUD would that count as 4 api interfaces?  Note, they also want a python backend via Flask and a react frontend and a database.
What do they mean by 3-5 api interfaces?

Comment: It means connect to 3-5 apis. For instance you might connect to: youtube, google-maps, & facebook apis in the same application. (I think)

Comment: I would guess they want the page you build to interact with 3-5 APIs

Comment: I feel like this is part of the test lol Question #1 can you decipher strange business requirements?

Comment: It also sounds like a BS request. In my experience, interviews that ask you to complete a project as part of a job interview tend to be time-wasters.

Comment: Never heard of it. The best I could say is whether they have an Sqlite back-end and see if concurrency might be an issue

Comment: @admcfajn yup: how much free work can I get from a developer. No thanks.

Comment: That's way too much effort for an interview. I'm not against interview coding projects in principal, if you don't have any project samples you can show them then getting you to show your work is reasonable before they hire you. But they should be like 1 hour's worth of work, maaaybe 2. Just enough for you to show your knowledge and practices. A backend, frontend and database with a bunch of APIs sounds way over the top.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you use 3 to 5 different API calls/services from a certain API, for example:

```
GET  api.com/content
POST api.com/login
GET  api.com/user/{id}/products
```

This would count as 3 different API interfaces. Using CRUD should also validate the interface request.

The truth is there is some ambiguity on the request, but as long as you can justify your choices I guess there is no wrong answer.